# add myself back to sudo'ers list

Tags: ubuntu, unix, sudo

i've got a computer running Ubuntu 9.10 Server, and i added myself to a new group using the following command:

```
sudo usermod -G my_group me
```

i learned that command removes me from all the groups i *was* in (like the `sudo` group), and adds me to *only* `my_group`.

the problem:

- i was the only one in the `sudo` group, there is now no one
- i never enabled/created a root
- i don't remember setting one up when i installed the OS
- when i type `su` and try the same password as my account (the account i set up when i installed the OS), it is not accepted

did i screw up my computer?  do i need to spend an hour re-doing everything?  or is there a way to recover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i got to work:

- reboot the computer by holding ctrl+alt+del at the initial log in screen after boot (physically at the machine, not ssh)
- hold the esc key while booting
- the computer entered some weird state where it has both a root shell and a login prompt.  i was able to enter a command in between the pauses while the login prompt was checking my username/password
- i added my username to the sudo line in /etc/group

i don't know what i was in, but i don't think it was the grub bootloader.  any information on why it just gave me a root shell when i held esc during boot instead of grub would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a root account already installed, since you don't know the password you can access is from single user mode then change your accounts groups.

to boot into single user mode:

- At the GRUB menu, use the arrows to select the boot entry you want to modify.
- press e to edit the entry
- use the arrows to go to kernel line
- press e to edit this entry
- at the end of the line add the word single
- press ESC to go back to the parent menu
- press b to boot this kernel

You will be presented with a shell prompt and you'll be logged in as root without providing a password, you can test this by running `whoami`. You may also need to mount certain partitions depending on your setup and where the binaries you'll need are located.

Comment: how do i get to the grub menu?  i think i'm supposed to press the `Esc` key after the BIOS screen goes away, but when i do this i get strange behavior at the login screen, and no menu.  thanks.

Comment: You're supposed to press Esc when you see "Grub loading... ".

Answer (score 0):

try `passwd root`
it might work if you never set up root

Comment: just gave it a try, no luck